# Soap UI test design for Image Base64 String - What and How to test?

Tags: testing, groovy, base64, automated-tests, soapui

I have to test an API that allows user to create a profile and profile has a picture. Currently API taking picture value as base64 string.

Something like this.

```
<ImageContent>BASE64 STRING VALUE</ImageContent>
```

In UI code is decode this Base64 and shows image.

*Now I have to write a test to test the API. Is there any Library available in SOAP UI Groovy Script that I can write and provide solid test around this?*

I searched the Internet and found this, but its not the complete answer and decided to create this question.

reference link :
http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Decode-base64-string-to-an-image-pdf-or-png-using-groovy/td-p/19846

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. What do you want to test exactly? That the image is correctly saved on server? Why don't change your approach and make the checks for the correctness of the image in your API, and in case that it's not correct return an error, and make your tests around this.

Comment: My question is around How i can test or any specific scenario ? Currently i can't use assert and I am stuck there because of very huge string value